# Fedora updates make Eclipse forget Java

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora, yum

(Not sure if this is an okay place to ask, but i'll try). After installing some updates in Fedora 16, Eclipse no longer knows how to use Java files. It can't make them, or compile them, or format the syntax. It's just eclipse without any Java whatsoever. I checked the yum.log and it installed about 6 eclipse updates and 2 java updates. A solution I found on the internet was to delete .eclipse and have eclipse regenerate it, but that didn't fix anything. Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced a similar problem, it would be best in my opinion to remove every package for java and eclipse all together. You can find installed packages with:

```
sudo rpm -qa | grep keyword
```

where keyword would be for example 'jre', 'jdk' or 'eclipse'.

Once you find the packages you don't want, remove them with

```
sudo yum remove packagename
```

Then I would recommend you to skip default jdk available for linux and install the one provided from the Oracle website: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

I have installed version 6 myself as I had some maven problems (m2eclipse) with Java 7.

Download the rpm, install it and set you path to java in .bashrc file.

Check all your installed jre/jdk with

```
sudo alternatives --config java
```

or

```
sudo alternatives --config javac
```

and set the apropriate option if necessary.

Next, go to the eclipse website and download the latest stable release of eclipse and you should be fine. You can integrate it with the desktop as well so you won't have to start it from the command line every time.

Comment: I get exit code 13 when trying to launch eclipse, along with what seems to be eclipse.ini.

Comment: what do you get when you run 'java --version' and 'javac --version'? Do you start your eclipse from 'eclipse.sh' shell script? Pls provide full error trace

Answer (score 1):

The problem is documented here:

http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2012-January/161092.html

and this is the bug:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=760454

Basically, we were caught between a rock and a hard place and had to break a packaging loop so this broke people's existing installations.  Move `~/.eclipse` and restart Eclipse and you should be fine.

```
$ mv ~/.eclipse{,.bakBug760454}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all of the available eclipse* packages. "Eclipse" itself is just a plug-in platform with a lot of UI components, it's not a Java IDE unless you also install those plug-ins.  It's possible that the packaging was changed in a way that the Java plug-ins were no longer included in the packages you have installed after the upgrade completed.